# How to simplify a fraction involving factorials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

I have following term:

$$\frac{\frac{3^{2k+2}}{(2k+2)!}}{\frac{2^{2k}}{(2k)!}}=\frac{3^{2k+2}\cdot(2k)!}{(2k+2)! \cdot 3^{2k}}=9\cdot\frac{(2k)!}{(2k+2)!}$$

I know that you can simplify even further to $$\frac{9}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}$$ but I do not get the intermediate steps.

I know that $$(n+1)! = n!(n+1) = (n-1)! \cdot (n+1) \cdot n$$

**but I still do not know how to apply this on terms different from $(n+1)$ (e.g. $(2n+2)$)?**

Comment: $$(2k+2)!=(2k+2)\cdot(2k+1)! = (2k+2)(2k+1)\cdot(2k)!.$$

Comment: Right $2k$ is in our case just our $n$ wow this was simple :D - do you right an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right it can be simplified

$$9\frac{(2k)!}{(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!} = \frac{9}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}$$